# How can I solve a Permission denied error to a mounted volume when running a podman pod?

Tags: podman

the following kube file is used for a mariadb pod within a Centos 8 VM with podman version 4.3.1:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  annotations:
    bind-mount-options:/home/myuser/mysql-data: Z
  labels:
    app: mariadb-local
  name: MARIADB-local
spec:

  containers:
    - args:
        - mariadbd
      image: docker.io/library/mariadb:10.10
      name: mariadb
      ports:
        - containerPort: 3306
          hostPort: 3306
      resources: {}
      envFrom:
        - configMapRef:
            name: maria-local-config
      securityContext:
        capabilities:
          drop:
            - CAP_MKNOD
            - CAP_NET_RAW
            - CAP_AUDIT_WRITE
      tty: true
      volumeMounts:
        - name: database-volume
          mountPath: /var/lib/mysql

  restartPolicy: Never

  volumes:
    - hostPath:
        path: /home/myuser/mysql-data
        type: Directory
      name: database-volume
```

The file was generated from podman from a running pod and the mounting to the data directory was added. Within the original file there is another container with an application that is accessing the database but for local development I only need the database container.

If I try to start the pod it is not working as expected and I get the following error message:

```
Entrypoint script for MariaDB Server 1:10.10.3+maria~ubu2204 started. 
find: ‘/var/lib/mysql/’: Permission denied
```

The file permissions on the host system are the following:

```
drwxrwxrwx. 7  100998  100998 4096  mysql-data
```

It seems that the volume mount is not working properly because of a permission problem.
According to [this](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/rootless-podman-user-namespace-modes) documentation the pod should run as myuser with id 1000. But

```
podman top -l user,huser
```

gives me

```
USER        HUSER
mysql       100998
```

How can I change the namespace to myuser in the pod file? That user is the owner of the directory and should have all the rights needed. I would expect that the HUSER would be the user that also started the pod (myuser) but that doesn't seem to be that case.

I can make the pod run if I use setenforce 0 but that should not be a permanent solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to used a named volume rather than bind-mounting a host path. When you use a named volume, the volume inherits the ownership and permissions of the underlying mountpoint.

The following configuration runs without errors:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: maria-local-config
data:
  MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  annotations:
    bind-mount-options:/home/myuser/mysql-data: Z
  labels:
    app: mariadb-local
  name: MARIADB-local
spec:

  containers:
    - args:
        - mariadbd
      image: docker.io/library/mariadb:10.10
      name: mariadb
      ports:
        - containerPort: 3306
          hostPort: 3306
      resources: {}
      envFrom:
        - configMapRef:
            name: maria-local-config
      securityContext:
        capabilities:
          drop:
            - CAP_MKNOD
            - CAP_NET_RAW
            - CAP_AUDIT_WRITE
      tty: true
      volumeMounts:
        - name: database-volume
          mountPath: /var/lib/mysql

  restartPolicy: Never

  volumes:
    - name: database-volume
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: database-volume
```

The above manifests:

1. Create a pod (`MARIADB-local`)
2. Create two containers (the `-infra` container, and `MARIADB-local-mariadb`)
3. Populate the environment of the `MARIADB-local-mariadb` pod with the values from the `data` section of the `maria-local-config` ConfigMap

Comment: Ok that seems to work, thanks. Can I access the data on the volume claim somehow or where is it located? I want to copy the content of the /home/myuser/mysql-data to have all the data ready.

Comment: If you're just looking to take a backup of the data, you can `exec` into the container and run `tar` to stdout and save that locally. In most cases, using named volumes like this is going to be a better solution than bind mounting a host directory (unless you *really* need shared access to that data, which doesn't make sense for something like a database server).

Comment: In this case it is more like a restore of the data since the data resist on the host system within the given path. So far I have now an empty database. So I have to do a dump from the old database and restore it into the container with the persistent volume I guess?

Answer (score 2):

There is the possibility to call the play kube command with the

```
--userns=keep-id
```

option, that seems to do what is intended.

From podman-kube-play documentation:

> keep-id: creates a user namespace where the current user’s UID:GID are mapped to the same values in the container. For containers created by root, the current mapping is created into a new user namespace.